# Как разместить кнопку под WebView?

Tags: android, android-layout

Как мне разместить кнопки под `WebView`? Пока они сливаются вместе.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

<WebView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/web_view"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
</WebView>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

    <Button
        android:text="Call"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/call"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:width="1dp" />

    <Button
        android:text="Exit"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/exit"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:width="1dp" />
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Скриншот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например, вот так:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/web_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </WebView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/call"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Call"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/exit"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Exit"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```